# DataSet Performance

Tags: sql-server

Could someone explain to me why there such a difference when it comes to filling and updating DataSet?
Currently I am working on program that takes data from one db and puts them into second db. Original DB contains quite a lot of data. I wonder why it is so fast for program to fill DataSet with data, but so long to update.

Code schema looks like that:

```
Create Connections;
OpenConnections();
Create DataAdapter1, DataAdapter2;
Create CommandBuilder1, CommandBuilder2;
Create DataSet;
DataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet, Connection1);
DataAdapter2.Update(DataSet, Connection2);
CloseConnections();
```

Comment: Your question sounds like it's basically "why does writing take longer than reading", correct? There are **many** factors at play here - server configuration, network, storage, what the code itself is doing, software versions...but in general, writing data takes longer than reading because there's just more work involved.

Comment: Correct, I just wonder what is happening behind the code that there is such a duration time

Comment: The answer to that is *far* too large for a Stack Overflow answer. And if you want to know *everything* going on behind the code, some portions aren't known outside Microsoft (beyond maybe a handful of people).

Comment: Also, of interest is what tool you are using. I guess some flavor of .NET?

Comment: I use Odbc and SqlCe